# Eliminating linear combinations from lists

Tags: list-manipulation, linear-algebra

Suppose I have a list of simple expressions, something like:

```
list = {{a-b-2c-d+e+2f},{-a-2b-c+d+2e+f},{-2a-b+c+2d+e-f},{x-y-z},{-x+y-z},{-x-y+z}};
```

These expressions are going to become elements in a linear combination. But notice that the third element in this list is itself already a linear combination of the first two. Therefore, my "basis" really should be this list without one of the first three elements (it doesn't matter which one goes away, but for consistency I would like to remove the third of them). Is there an automated way in Mathematica to search a list of expressions like this, identify when elements are linear combinations of others, and then remove the extraneous elements?

Comment: "But notice that the third element in this list is itself already a linear combination of the first two."  Nope.  Check it (especially $e$).

Comment: Yeah, typo. Fixed now. Thank you for pointing it out!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take your list and fix it so that the 3rd element dependent on the first two:

```
list[[3]] = (list[[2]] + list[[1]])/3 // Expand;
list
(*
  {{2a + b - c - 2d - e + f}, {a + 2b + c - d - 2 e - f}, {-a + b + 2c + d - e - 2f},
   {x - y - z}, {-x + y - z}, {-x - y + z}}
*)
```

Convert system of linear functions to a matrix:

```
vars = Variables@list;
linsys = CoefficientArrays[Flatten@list, vars][[2]];
```

Extract linearly independent elements of `list`:

```
Extract[list, 
 FirstPosition[#, 1, Nothing] & /@ RowReduce[Transpose@linsys]]
(*
  {{a - b - 2 c - d + e + 2 f}, {-a - 2 b - c + d + 2 e + f},
   {x - y - z}, {-x + y - z}, {-x - y + z}}
*)
```

Or row reduce to get an equivalent basis:

```
RowReduce[linsys].vars // DeleteCases[0]
(*  {a - c - d + f, b + c - e - f, x, y, z}  *)
```

Comment: The example I started with *does* have the third entry dependent on the first two (element 2 minus element 1 is element 3). But regardless, your approach worked perfectly! Thank you!

Comment: @KevinAusman  You're welcome. (Maybe there's a typo in the question because elt. 2 minus elt. 1 should have a `+ e` in the expression, but there are no `e`.)

Comment: Huh. You are obviously correct about the typo. Thank you! Fixing it now.

Comment: And I accidentally, in trying to fix the problem, tried to edit your response! So sorry... I don't know how to withdraw my suggested edit. Clearly I didn't get enough sleep last nigh.

Comment: @KevinAusman No problem.  New users' edits of other posts go through a queue for approval.  Those who review it might reject it, if they spot the error.  If it does go through, it can be rolled back.  Hopefully they will see your comment and reject it.

Answer (score 3):

What I would do is replace symbols by numeric vectors with a function like

```
ClearAll[toNumbers];
toNumbers[list_, vars_] := 
  list /. Thread[vars -> IdentityMatrix[Length[vars]]];

toNumbers[{a, b, a + b}, {a, b}]
(*{{1, 0}, {0, 1}, {1, 1}}*)
```

then perform some linear algebra and convert the result back into symbols with something like

```
ClearAll[fromNumbers];
fromNumbers[list_, vars_] := Replace[
 list,
 x_ :> x.vars,
 {1}
];

fromNumbers[{{1, 0}, {0, 1}, {1, 1}}, {a, b}]
(*{a, b, a + b}*)
```

The linear algebra logic can be something like `Fold` which checks a vector and appends it to a list if it is linear independent form the vectors in the list:

```
Fold[
 f,
 {},
 {{1, 1, 0}, {0, 1, 0}, {1, 1, 1}}
]
```

where

```
ClearAll[f];
f[vecs_, vec_] := With[
   {
    vecs2 = Append[vecs, vec]
   },
   vecs2 /; MatrixRank[vecs2] == Length[vecs2]
];
f[vecs_, vec_] := vecs;
```

Gathering all together (except `f`):

```
ClearAll[leaveLinearIndependent];
leaveLinearIndependent[list_, vars_] := Replace[
  Fold[
   f,
   {},
   list /. Thread[vars -> IdentityMatrix[Length[vars]]]
   ],
 x_ :> x.vars,
 {1}
 ];

leaveLinearIndependent[{a, a + b, b, c}, {a, b, c}]
(*{a, a + b, c}*)
```

Answer (score 3):

```
list = {{a-b-2c-d+e+2f},{-a-2b-c+d+2e+f},
  {-2a-b+c+2d+e-f},{x-y-z},{-x+y-z},{-x-y+z}};
```

First extract coefficient arrays.

```
coeffArrays = Normal[CoefficientArrays[list]][[2,All,1]]               

(* ut[29]= {{1, -1, -2, -1, 1, 2, 0, 0, 0},
   {-1, -2, -1, 1, 2, 1, 0, 0, 0}, 
   {-2, -1, 1, 2, 1, -1, 0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, -1, -1}, 
   {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, -1, 1, -1}, {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, -1, -1, 1}} *)
```

Find null vectors of the transpose.

```
nulls = NullSpace[Transpose@dd]                                        

(* Out[30]= {{1, -1, 1, 0, 0, 0}} *)
```

We want to remove vectors in positions of last nonzero value in each null vector (of which there is but one, in this case). We can automate the task of finding the list to remove as below.

```
Flatten[Length[nulls[[1]]] + 1 -
    Map[FirstPosition[#,Except[0],Heads->False]&,
      Map[Reverse,nulls]]]                                               

(* Out[41]= {3} *)
```